# How can I make the href for a button use urls.py?

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I need to add a 'Cancel' button to my ModelForm, I am using crispy forms but when I add `href='personnel-index'` to redirect back to the list view, it does not. I've checked their documentation but no luck nor any luck on Google.

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14423114/1297812

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes the browser's 'Back' button does just as well as a 'Cancel' button in a web form, but if you are absolutely sure you need one, you can always use the HTML object in crispy forms.  Something like this would work:

```
HTML("""<a class="classes-for-styling" href="/personnel/list/">Cancel</a>""")
```

And, even better, you can include context aware tags to avoid hard-coding urls into your form:

```
HTML("""<a class="classes-for-styling" href="{% url 'personnel-index' %}">Cancel</a>""")
```

Then it's just up to you to style your link so it looks like a button.

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily ideal, but this should handle most situations.

```
self.helper.add_input(Button('cancel', 'Cancel', css_class='btn-default', onclick="window.history.back()"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I can't comment the existing solution because my reputation isn't good enough. That's why I am adding the code example for HTML (crispy form object) solution that was proposed above:

```
class MoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mood

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MoodForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        layout = Layout(
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('Save', 'Save', css_class='button white'),
                HTML('<a class="btn btn-warning" href={% url "mood:list" %}>Cancel</a>'),
            ),  
        )
        self.helper.add_layout(layout)
```

The most important stuff here is:

```
ButtonHolder(
    Submit('Save', 'Save', css_class='button white'),
    HTML('<a class="btn btn-warning" href={% url "mood:list" %}>Cancel</a>'),
)
```

It renders two buttons 'Save' and 'Cancel'.